# Brackets convert to %26%2340%3B instead of %28 in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, urldecode

I use this line to get a full route name in Codeigniter:

`$path = implode("/", func_get_args());`

for example if user types `https://example.com/test/test5678/test+(123)`

I'll get this: `test5678/test+(123)`

It's kind of weird. Everything goes normal but the brackets:

if I `urldecode($path)`, I'll get `test5678/test (123)`

**Then** when I encode it again (`urlencode($path)`) the brackets convert to `%5C%26%5C%2340%5C%3B` instead of `%28` or `(` .(same result for `)`)

What is wrong? How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Dunno, looks good: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/786623d15b341b0b358e0ae2d55c198f197fa8af

Comment: why are you trying to decode a decoded url? urldecode, decodes any %## encoding in the given string. Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character.(from php manual)